# Verify why object is only garbage collected on second garbage collection run

Tags: android, garbage-collection

For learning purposes I am currently experimenting with Garbage Collection (Pixel 2, Android 10 -> `ART`). My observation for the following experiment is that `CountActivity` is never deleted on the first explicit garbage collection run, but only at the second explicit garbage collection run. I want to understand why it isn't deleted on the first run. I assume it's due to some kind of generational garbage collection, but I want to verify it. How can I "watch" what the garbage collection does? E.g. is it possible to see the internal generations in which the garbage collection groups the heap?

My test example is as follows:

1. `MainActivity`, which shows a Button "Show CountActivity"
2. `CountActivity` which is shown when the Button "Show CountActivity" in the `MainActivity` is pressed.
3. I end the `CountActivity` using my system back key

After this, I force an explicit garbage collection run, capture a heap. `CountActivity`is still there. After forcing a second explicit garbage collection run and again capturing a heap, the `CountActivity` is gone. Now I still want to understand why it takes two garbage collection runs.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener {
      showCountActivity()
    }

  }

  private fun showCountActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, CountActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
  }

}
```

**CountActivity**

```
class CountActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count)
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share your GC log files so that we can see what's actually happening?

Comment: sure. can you give me some hints how to collect these? guess you are not only talking about the logcat entries, right?

Comment: When you have a heap dump already, you should be able to find out which references to the object do exist.

Comment: @Holger issue is not that there's a reference to it, then it also wouldn't be cleaned up on the second run. must have to do with generational GC I assume, but I want to verify it.

Comment: I had no reason to assume that the heap dumps are identical. In fact, you already stated that they aren’t, as there’s at least that difference regarding the presence of the object in question. When there are no references to it in the first dump, we’re not only touching the way, the garbage collector works, but also how the heap dump is created. Are there any other consequences besides being able to see the object in the heap dump?

Comment: this wont answer your question, but I can recommend this talk about gc on android: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKMsPrDMprE You probably already found that though.

Comment: @Holger no, there are no other consequences. it's there in the first heap dump and gone in the second, nothing is done in between.

Comment: @muetzenflo Thanks, goes in some interesting details, but not in those answering this question \:

Answer (score 2):

ART (the Android RunTime) uses what's referred to as a [generational garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Generational_GC_(ephemeral_GC)), which basically creates buckets of objects based on when those objects were created (on the theory that newer objects are more likely to need to be garbage collected, since that's where all the temporary objects (builders, other intermediate objects, etc.) will end up.  Thus, a garbage collection may not necessarily collect all generations of objects.

Here's some basic information about how Android's garbage collector works: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview

You can verify this by taking and analyzing a heap dump in Android Studio and noting that there is not a path to any GC roots from object in question.

Here's some very detailed documentation about the details of the GC (more likely to be useful to people working on ART itself, but still informative - the [ergonomics](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug#ergonomics) section in particular discusses the generational collection a bit): https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug

Comment: thank you, but is there any way to really check if this is the case? I really want to see (not assume, though I also believe it's due ti generational) which type of GC was run and if possible which object is in which bucket.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I could imagine the easiest way to do it is writing a small test program and using builtin tools like the debugger of your IDE

Comment: @riggedCoinflip You won't see that in the debugger. Some parts of the GC are visible in the systrace, but it's hard to interpret without deeper knowledge. Also it seems only to show which kind of GC was run, not how the heaps look.

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification, i didn't know that.Was never at a point so far where I had to worry about garbage collection

Comment: You should be able to check via a heap dump, though.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the exact type and working of your garbage collection is best done by analyzing the logging it writes, which can automatically be analyzed by a free tool on the website gceasy.io that illustrate this in their blog:

https://blog.gceasy.io/2017/05/09/understanding-android-gc-logs/

If you would learn from the logs that you were to have a problem (e.g.: memory leak, performance issue) that you needed to further investigate you may want to create a heap dump and analyse all the objects and object references of your choosing with e.g. custom code:

https://rhye.org/post/advanced-android-heap-analysis/

Or maybe through a web application like ahat:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/tools/ahat/README.txt

Comment: thanks for your reply. which logs do you refer to? logcat output?

Comment: Yes the blog refers to this page with more information https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat